# transmit from sb to sb or transmit to sb from sb

Tags: prepositional-phrases

> Dengue virus is transmitted **to people from mosquito**.
>   Dengue virus is transmitted **from mosquito to people**.

What is the difference between these
two sentences?

Answer (score 3):

There is almost no difference. **To** tells of the person/thing that has caught the virus. **From** tells of the person/thing from which the virus infection originates. In other words, **to** is all about the **target**, whereas **from** is all about the **source** of the virus/infection. Whether you begin with **to** or  **from** could be just a matter of style, or it could be a matter of importance, as when the reader is expected to be more interested in the source of the infection than in those who are likely to be infected:

> Two people and three cows have been found dead in an area in the countryside. Autopsy has shown a deadly virus was the cause of death. The virus is known to be transmitted from mosquitos to both humans and animals.